# How to silently uninstall Visio remotely

Tags: powershell, uninstallation, visio

I have to remove Microsoft Visio silentlyy from a lot computer. I tried Uninstall-Package and wmic commands, via PsExec, seems working but not uninstalling, still there. It is for Visio 2016 and Visio 2019. Does uninstall string work if I get? But I have to force uninstall silently, its important.

The uninstall string: `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller\setup.exe" /uninstall VISPRO /dll OSETUP.DLL MsiExec.exe /X{90150000-0051-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE} MsiExec.exe /X{90150000-0054-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}`

```
$Command = 
'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*',
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*',
'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ItemProperty $_ | Where-Object {
        $_.DisplayName -like '*Visio*'
    } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'UninstallString'
}

Write-Host $Command
```

Comment: Are you getting some error with this ? or you want to remove from local computer or remote computer.

Comment: No error. It seem success. Only wmic returns 1603 error. Remote computer.

Comment: because the UninstallString is not executing. if you try to uninstall manually with the uninstall string, it does not happen.